# Make a page an archive of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am new to Wordpress and would like to know if this is duable.

I have a page which is create using visual composer (since the content changes every week). Now I would like to add a listing of custom posts into it (using a shortcode) and also make this page the archive for this custom post type. Is this possible?

The best idea I came up with was to create a custom post type, add a archive-myposttype.php and do a query for the page in it. But is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a custom post type and associated archive page sounds like a great solution. As the developer you have full control of the template layout and it will always be consistent.

Adding shortcodes from visual composer comes into play if you want the list of custom posts to live on a page other than the archive. I'm sure there's an element within visual composer that will create a custom loop for that post type (and probably a custom taxonomy within that post type). That way you have the flexibility to add those posts wherever you want to. That said, you have to like the way visual composer structures and styles the output. Additionally, you could customize the output of the shortcode and have the best of both worlds.

So to answer the question if it's doable? YES!

> But is there any other way?

Yes, you could add a custom query to a template and loop our you custom posts wherever you want them.

All three options are viable. It depends on what the needs of your end user are, and your comfort level with coding custom templates.

Comment: The problem with a custom post type is that I need to embbed some HTML that changes alot into the archive template. How to do that? Should I create several pages and query for them inside the template?

Comment: By "Embedding HTML" are you refering to changing the structure of the post? Like, unique layouts for different posts? I think I'd handle that in the content area of each post. Using Visual composer there would accomodate that.

Comment: No each post should have the same layout, only the archive template needs to embedd some HTML before the listing and after the listing (not single post). And that HTML is created with Visual Composer.

Comment: I answered something like this recently. Make yourself a page and within the archive template use get_page to pull that content in.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook were you using Visual Composer as well? Did you have any problems with inline styles not getting included?

Comment: Yeah, if you have static content in a page, you could add it to the archive template. You can actually skip using `get_page()`, and instead use `echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);` and target a specific post id. You could do that before and one after and pull content from two different pages if you need to wrap your custom post entry. There are some downsides to this approach, though. Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @blejzz inline styles? Yuk.